# Allowed memory size exhausted when calling "request" on GuzzleHttp\Client

Tags: php, guzzle

I am using the following method to call an API (using Guzzle, PHP HTTP client 6.5.2):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$response = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/api');
```

It works fine for a few calls, but if there are a large amount of data and I have to make the request multiple times in a loop (to fetch data page by page):

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();

do {

  //...

  $response = $client->request('GET', 'https://example.com/api');

  //...

} while($pageNumber <= $totalPages);
```

Then I will eventually get the following memory error in the middle of the loop:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 268435456 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 1384448 bytes) in guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlHandler.php on line 40

The size of the returned `$response` is almost 1MB. Also, it's not the case that it's an infinite loop. The `$pageNumber` is being calculatedly correctly and the loop ends for a smaller amount of data. The memory error happens when there are like total number of 200 pages.

Any idea how I can get this fixed?

Comment: What's the `$response` that you are getting? Is it so big? Also, I don't see `$pageNumber++` being done anywhere?

Comment: So it means some variable is not reset in loop or contains too much information. Show more relevant code as now it looks fine

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at [this issue on GitHub](https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle/issues/2555), could be related to your case.

Otherwise there is not enough information to say something. The issue easily can be not related to Guzzle at all.

The best option for you is to profile your code with Blackfire (you can see an example in the issue above, on GitHub).